# React JS - SVG file href not displaying in my app

Tags: reactjs

I have this svg and includes xlink:href that contains the path of the images

```
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="190" height="76" id="logo" xlink:href="./logos/pic1.png">
```

And in my css file

```
.item {
    background-image: url(./pic.svg);
}
```

When I click the svg it shows the logo which pic1.png but in my react app it doesn't show. Is there something wrong here, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this in react

make sure your path is correct

```
<svg>
+
+
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="190" height="76" id="logo" xlinkHref="./logos/pic1.png">
</svg>
```